# PHP array adding new data in specific place

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a php array called $data with keys as numeric values, as below:

```
$data['5']="Data 5";
$data['6']="Data 6";
$data['9']="Data 9";
```

I then have an addition to this variable as follows:

```
$data['new']="New Data";
```

But i need to place this new data into the $data array before a specific key that is returned by $key variable.

So for example if $key=6 then the new data addition needs to be added just before the 6 in the $data array.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `$data['6']`, add `$data['new']`, and then add `$data['6']` again?

Comment: problem with that is that then the 6 and the new one will end up going at the bottom, i need it in the exact same place.

Comment: googling gave me this link: ``array_insert_before`` and ``array_insert_after`` http://eosrei.net/articles/2011/11/php-arrayinsertafter-arrayinsertbefore

Comment: how about array of key-value entries, like array(key=>"new",value=>"new Data") ? Then you can use numeric indexing and can have ordered entries.

Comment: Kita, that array_insert_before seems promising but cant seem to get it to work, i copied the function, how do i then call that function for my use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, if you want to add it on particular position than you can try code like this.

```
$data['5']="Data 5";
$data['6']="Data 6";
$data['9']="Data 9";

$additionData['new']="New Data";
function array_insert($arr, $insert, $position) {
    $i =0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if ($i == $position) {
                    foreach ($insert as $ikey => $ivalue) {
                            $ret[$ikey] = $ivalue;
                    }
            }
            $ret[$key] = $value;
            $i++;
    }
    return $ret;
}

  $data = array_insert($data,$additionData,2);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data);
```

and call this function like `array_insert($data,$additionData,2);`

2 is the position.

Comment: Ram Sharma, the problem with this way is that the key values for the existing data seem to change.

Comment: Tried that but doesnt seem to be adding the new $additionData to the $data array, created a phpfiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a4x-h1m

Comment: John, Check fiddle now http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kz5-dvt. updated the code in my answer as well.